# How to write on a blackboard

Tags: stationery

How do we write on a blackboard with chalk pieces? From personal experience, I tend to write too lightly at times due to which others can't even read what is written. And, if I write with a bit of more force then, the chalk breaks. So, How can we write with a chalk on a blackboard such that the writing is clear and legible?

<sub>(P.S.-I am not sure about the tags, feel free to edit them..)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Not really a hack
A chalk holder
[image: Chalk in a holder]

Answer (score 2):

Most people use mere chalk pieces to write on a blackboard. If the chalk pieces are getting broken often, then either the chalk pieces are of not so good quality or the way you hold the chalk piece is not right. 
Chalk pieces are made up of ionic salt which is light and easily breakable and that is why we use it for writing on a rough surface.

If you hold the chalk piece at its centre while writing, the chalk piece is definitely going to break because of the torque acting on it. I would suggest holding the chalk piece just as how you hold a pen or pencil while writing on a notebook. But experienced people hold at its neck, I.e., few millimeters away from the tip which may help you apply more strength resulting darker font.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a hack that we use to present details on black board.

- Please dip the chalk in small quantity of water before use.

At first, as you write, your writings will be in lighter shades, but within a short duration it will become brighter. In this hack, no external force is required, as here it expects only our normal writing force. Moreover, this writing will last long and you may need to apply some force while rubbing the contents on board away.